# How to select from a table in SQL where element in a column contains only one feature of another column which in turn contains two features in itself?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a table1 in SQL as follows.

```
Team   PlayerID

Team1  12
Team2  56
Team1  78
Team1  96
Team3  23
Team2  45
Team3  89
Team3  78
```

Now I have a new table2 as

```
PlayerID  Gender

12        Male
56        Female
78        Female
96        Male
23        Female
45        Male
89        Female
78        Female
```

Is there a way to list out all the teams with only female genders?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You have to join table1 with table2 on condition that playerIDs are equual and gender is female. Have you had any attempts?

Comment: @marekful Yes I tried JOIN on two tables and used WHERE Gender = 'Female' but that returns me rows of Teams which contain Female gender, not teams exclusively containing Female gender. I tried a few other variations but couldn't come up with anything since I've only just begun to learn SQL.

Comment: You can find teams that have no males

Comment: Yes of course there's a way.

Comment: Where's your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join`, `group by`, and `having`:

```
select t.team
from teams t join
     players p
     on p.playerid = t.playerid
group by t.team
having min(gender) = max(gender) and min(gender) = 'Female';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure to have at least 1 player per team then this should work:

```
SELECT T1.Team
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.PlayerID = T2.PlayerID AND t2.Gender = 'Male'
GROUP BY T1.Team
Having COUNT(Gender) = 0
```